# Not able to position UIActivityIndicatorView correctly

Tags: ios, swift

I added an UIActivityIndicatorView to a scene, and it worked fine. Then I tried to add a small container and show the activity indicator on top of that.

This is the code I have.

```
func showActivityIndicator(uiView: UIView) {
    let container: UIView = UIView()
    container.frame = CGRect(x: 0.0, y: 0.0, width: 80.0, height: 80.0);
    container.center = uiView.center
    container.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 0.0, green: 0.0, blue: 0.0, alpha: 0.5)

    let activityIndicator = UIActivityIndicatorView()
    activityIndicator.frame = CGRect(x: 0.0, y: 0.0, width: 40.0, height: 40.0);
    activityIndicator.center = uiView.center
    activityIndicator.hidesWhenStopped = true
    activityIndicator.activityIndicatorViewStyle = UIActivityIndicatorViewStyle.gray

    container.addSubview(activityIndicator)
    uiView.addSubview(container)

    activityIndicator.startAnimating()
}
```

The container view is displayed in the middle of the screen, but there is no activity indicator. When I check the debug view hierarchy, I see the activity indicator is outside the view, in the lower right corner. Can any one please explain why it ended up there after I added the container? And how can I position it correctly?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there is an issue with below code

```
 activityIndicator.center = uiView.center
```

please try this

```
 activityIndicator.center = CGPoint(x: container.frame.size.width/2,y: container.frame.size.height/2)
```

Answer (score 0):

This will work:

```
func showActivityIndicator(uiView: UIView) {
      let container: UIView = UIView()
      container.frame = CGRect(x: 0.0, y: 0.0, width: 80.0, height: 80.0);
      container.center = uiView.center
      container.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 0.0, green: 0.0, blue: 0.0, alpha: 0.5)

      let activityIndicator = UIActivityIndicatorView()
      activityIndicator.center = container.center
      activityIndicator.hidesWhenStopped = true
      activityIndicator.activityIndicatorViewStyle = UIActivityIndicatorViewStyle.gray

     container.addSubview(activityIndicator)
     uiView.addSubview(container)

     activityIndicator.startAnimating()
}
```

Comment: No, this will not/did not work. In line 3 of the function "container.center = uiView.center".